# What is the meaning of this sentence: Her architectural wonders cause the people...?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/synopsis)

> Her architectural wonders cause the people in the dream -- projections of Cobb's subconscious -- to search for the intruder -- Ariadne -- like white blood cells drawn to a virus.

There are so many hyphens.

What is the meaning of the whole sentence?

Comment: Try analysing the sentence without the hyphen clauses: _**Her architectural wonders cause the people in the dream to search for the intruder like white blood cells drawn to a virus.**_ Once you understand that, try again with the clauses included.

Comment: Try to recall the rules regarding dashes. [Here](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/dashes.asp) is one source, for example. Then try to see if you can understand the meaning.

Comment: These aren't hyphens, but em dashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The people in the dream are

> projections of Cobb's subconscious.

The people in the dream are searching for the intruder.

The intruder is Adriane.

The people are searching like white blood cells drawn to a virus (white blood cells are part of your immune system and they fight viruses in your body)

So.

> The wonders cause the projections of Cobb's subconscious to search for Adriana (who is an intruder) like white blood cells drawn to a virus.

Answer (score 0):

Like commas, the "long" or "em" dash is used to break up the content of a sentence into sub-clauses.  Sometimes this is used to add *ancillary* information -- information which is *useful* but not *necessary* to the sentence.

Without these sub-clauses the sentence would simply read:

> Her architectural wonders cause the people in the dream to search for the intruder, like white blood cells drawn to a virus.

The first sub-clause, "projections of Cobb's subconscious", gives us more information on who the "people in the dream" are.  The second sub-clause, "Ariadne", tells us the name of the "intruder".  Neither is required to understand the sentence, but may still be useful information.